# Getting ResponseText without calling servlet using xmlhttprequest in IE(Any version)

Tags: javascript, ajax, internet-explorer, servlets

I'm using xmlhttprequest to call servlet. It is working fine in Firefox. But, in IE, only if I click refresh button, it is working(that too sometimes). Otherwise, it is not triggering. Moreover, the response text is displayed without calling the servlet. Is that using Cache or what? I don't have any idea . Help me out please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks one and all. Actually, I used "GET" instead of "POST" while calling the servlet in javascript. When I tried POST, it is working fine.

Answer (score 1):

MSIE is too eager in caching XHR requests. The only feasible way to get around this is to add a querystring with a timestamp to the XHR URL.

```
var url = '/url/to/your/servlet?' + new Date().getTime();
```

Answer (score 0):

To get around IEs over zelous caching of xhr you must get your servlet to add

```
Cach-Control:max-age=0
```

to the response headers of all html and .js files served up.

This will cause a revalidate of all files with this response, next time they are requested from IE including XHR. (must-revalidate did not seem to work on xhr loaded java script file, not sure why)
Be sure to clear the IE cache after this is done for it to take effect the next load.

IE will behave nicely with this setting. But dont put this into production of course.